# How to serialize relationship in django rest?

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Try to serialize this Models

Model:

```
    class Order (models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        date_create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_change = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        summ =models.CharField(max_length=15,default='0')
        delivery = models.ForeignKey('Delivery')
        success = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        paymentMethod = models.ForeignKey('Payments')
        def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.id)

    class OrderProduct(models.Model):
        order=models.ForeignKey('Order')
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        date_create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_change = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        product = models.ForeignKey('product.Product')
        additionals = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)
        count = models.IntegerField()
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.id


    class Delivery(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        date_create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_change = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        delivery_time = models.DateTimeField()
        delivery_adress = models.TextField()
        phone = models.TextField()
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.phone

    class Payments(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        date_create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_change = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        title = models.TextField();
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.title
```

Serializers:

```
class DeliverySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Delivery
        fields = ('id', 'delivery_time','delivery_adress','phone')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Delivery.objects.create(**validated_data)   


class PaymentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Payments
        fields = ('id', 'title')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Payments.objects.create(**validated_data)   



class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    delivery = DeliverySerializer(read_only=True)
    paymentMethod = PaymentsSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'delivery', 'paymentMethod','summ','success') 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        deliverys_data = validated_data.pop('delivery')
        paymentsMethod_data = validated_data.pop('paymentMethod')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for delivery_data in deliverys_data:
            Delivery.objects.create(order=order, **delivery_data)
        for paymentMethod_data in paymentsMethod_data:
            Payments.objects.create(order=order, **paymentMethod_data)
        return order
```

View:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def order_post(request, format=None):

   #List all snippets, or create a new snippet.

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I need to get data by 1 packet, and then write data in DB

EveryTime I get a error:
    deliverys_data = validated_data.pop('delivery')
KeyError: 'delivery'

Example of  JSON packet
[{"delivery":{"delivery_time":"2016-05-31T12:18:47Z","delivery_adress":"123","phone":"123"},"paymentMethod":{"id":1,"title":"123124123"},"summ":"23","success":false}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `KeyError: 'delivery'` because you have set `delivery` field as `read_only`. If DRF finds this field in the input, it will ignore that field.

From docs on [`read_only` argument:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments)

> Read-only fields are included in the API output, but should not be
>   included in the input during create or update operations. Any
>   `'read_only'` fields that are incorrectly included in the serializer
>   input will be ignored.

Also, since you are using `paymentMethod` field in the `create()` method, you need to tell DRF to consider that field also in the input.

So, you need to **remove the `read_only` argument from your serializer for both `delivery` and `paymentMethod` fields** so that these fields are considered when deserializing.

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    delivery = DeliverySerializer() # remove read_only argument
    paymentMethod = PaymentsSerializer() # remove read_only argument
```

Secondly, you are sending the data incorrectly. You need to **send a single `order` input instead of list of orders you are sending.**

```
# send without the list 
{"delivery":{"delivery_time":"2016-05-31T12:18:47Z","delivery_adress":"123","phone":"123"},"paymentMethod":{"id":1,"title":"123124123"},"summ":"23","success":false}
```

Comment: just removed "read_only", and send correct json, and now I get code 500 with     return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: order_order.delivery_id may not be NULL

Comment: This is because you are creating `Order` first without creating `Delivery`.  As per your model, you should first create `Delivery` and then use that to create `Order` by passing created `delivery` to it.

Comment: but in example http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album

they first of all - make album

Comment: Yes, they create `Album` first and then `Track` because `Album` is FK to `Track`. Similarly, you should create `Delivery` first and then `Order` because `Delivery` is FK to `Order`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205045/create-argument-after-must-be-a-mapping-not-unicode
Find another 1 example

Comment: @Weit I think it would be better that maybe you create another question for solving this error. You should post the complete traceback there with the code you are trying. Also, you can accept this ans if this solved your current question.

Comment: Thanks, you really solved my current problem. 
About question in comment - it solved in anothre question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721134/how-to-serialize-relation/37725480#37725480

Answer (score 0):

> EveryTime I get a error: deliverys_data = validated_data.pop('delivery') KeyError: 'delivery'

This is to be expected since the `OrderSerialzier` has `DeliverySerializer` flagged as `read_only`.
If you want to get the data writable, you'll need to remove that flag first.

Comment: Without it I get: "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
    ]

Comment: The error you mention should also happen with DeliverySerializer set to read_only. You expect a single Order and send JSON for a list of orders.