# What is a Python mapping?

Tags: python, syntax, typeerror

Say I have a function `func` and an object `obj` of class `Class`. I have the following error:

```py
>>> func(**obj)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: func() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Class
```

Hence my question: what is a mapping? Are all mappings subclasses of `dict`? Or is there a list of methods (e.g. `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, ...) that `Class` has to implement to be considered a mapping?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/typesmapping.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205045/create-argument-after-must-be-a-mapping-not-unicode

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping

Comment: Trying to cast some types? Can you give more detail?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The term "mapping" is described in [the Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping) as:

> A container object that supports arbitrary key lookups and implements
> the methods specified in the `Mapping` or `MutableMapping` abstract base
> classes. Examples include `dict`, `collections.defaultdict`,
> `collections.OrderedDict` and `collections.Counter`.

The requirements to subclass `collections.abc.Mapping` are described in [its docstring](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/_collections_abc.py):

> A Mapping is a generic container for associating key/value
> pairs.
>
> This class provides concrete generic implementations of all
> methods except for `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__`.

So you can define a new mapping type by subclassing `collections.abc.Mapping`, and implementing three methods: `__len__`, `__getitem__`, and `__iter__`.

```
>>> from collections.abc import Mapping
>>> def func(**kwargs):
...   print(kwargs)
...
>>> class MyMapping(Mapping):
...   def __len__(self):
...     return 1
...   def __getitem__(self, k):
...     return 'bananas'
...   def __iter__(self):
...     return iter(['custard'])
...
>>> func(**MyMapping())
{'custard': 'bananas'}
```

Answer (score 7):

According to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping):

> A container object that supports arbitrary key lookups and implements the methods specified in the Mapping or MutableMapping abstract base classes.
> Examples include:
>
> - dict
> - collections.defaultdict
> - collections.OrderedDict
> - collections.Counter.

The class is a [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) if it implements all methods from the [Mapping / MutableMapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping).

If you will create a Mapping/MutableMapping derived class and implement all of this, you will get a class that is a mapping.